# what's the portable way to reset getopt()?

Tags: posix, libc, getopt, sus

i'm aiming the `getopt()` machinery at my own argv-like array, after having used it on the real argv. the interface is non-reentrant (holds state), and various implementations are reset in different ways.

- in XPG3/SVID it's `optreset = 1;` (freebsd, macosx)
- in XPG4/POSIX/SUS it's `optind = 1;` (suse tumbleweed)
- in Linux/GLIBC it's also `optind = 0;` (debian)

i don't want to autoconf just for this.

what's a reliable set of `#ifdef`'s?

Comment: what's working at the moment is https://github.com/dnsdb/dnsdbq/commit/efa68c0499c3b5b4a1238318345e5e466a7fd99f

Answer (score 0):

The only standard thing is setting `optind = 1`.

The SUSv4 [standard](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getopt.html) makes no mention of `optreset` and declares `optind = 0` "unspecified":

> If the application sets `optind` to zero before calling `getopt()`, the behavior is unspecified.

Otherwise, the standard it vague, and does not say anything at all about calling `getopt()` multiple times, neither allowing it nor declaring it undefined.

Also, there are no defines which say if `optind = 0` or `optreset` are supported (fwiw the former is supported on OpenBSD, but not on FreeBSD, and the latter on Linux/musl, but not on Linux/glibc), so there can't be any reliable way to detect it via `#ifdef`s.

**Weren't for bugs** in fancy `getopt/_long` implementations (see below), **just setting `optind = 1`** to restart `getopt()` should work fine as long as

**a)** you don't use any [GNU extensions](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getopt.3.html):

> A program that scans multiple argument vectors,  or  rescans  the  same
>          vector  more than once, **and wants to make use of GNU extensions such as
>          `+` and `-` at  the  start  of  optstring,  or  changes  the  value  of
>          `POSIXLY_CORRECT`  between scans**, must reinitialize `getopt()` by resetting
>          `optind` to `0`,

**b)** you don't restart the `getopt()` in the middle, before it has returned `-1`. Eg. from [FreeBSD's `getopt`](https://github.com/freebsd/freebsd/blob/master/lib/libc/stdlib/getopt.c):

```
#define BADCH   (int)'?'
#define BADARG  (int)':'
#define EMSG    ""
...
int
getopt(int nargc, char * const nargv[], const char *ostr)
{
        static char *place = EMSG;              /* option letter processing */
        ...
        if (optreset || *place == 0) {          /* update scanning pointer */
                optreset = 0;
                ...
                        place = EMSG;
                        return (-1);
                ...
                        place = EMSG;
                        return (-1);
                ...
                        place = EMSG;
                        if (strchr(ostr, '-') == NULL)
                                return (-1);
        ...
                return (BADCH);
        ...
                                return (BADARG);
        ...
                        return (BADCH);
        ...
        return (optopt);                        /* return option letter */
}
```

#### Bugs

The glibc implementation of `getopt` will [cling to stale state](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=25658) even after returning `-1`. This may result in stupid bugs and crashes if the old strings are freed.

The OpenBSD implementation will do [likewise](https://marc.info/?l=openbsd-tech&m=158397808611554&w=2), but **only** when a bogus `-` option is used, as in `getopt("q", ["prog", "-q-", NULL])`. Notice that OpenBSD's `getopt_long` implementation may have made its way as the default `getopt()` into other systems like Solaris and Android.

Comment: those approaches were not portable across systems were tested. what we found that happens to work everywhere we tried it is https://github.com/dnsdb/dnsdbq/commit/efa68c0499c3b5b4a1238318345e5e466a7fd99f

Comment: Nope, that's broken. `optreset` is not supported on Solaris. What system exactly did you try `optind = 1` on (with the conditions described in the answer) which did not work?

Comment: we installed a Solaris 11.4 VM, did a pkg install of git and cc and were then able to build using "CC=gcc make" and the changes shown in the github link above.

Comment: Great, maybe they have added `optreset` to very recent versions of Solaris. Or you were using some compat library. But, please, what EXACT system did you try "those approaches" (ie as described in my answer) on and did NOT work. Thanks.

Comment: mosvy, ty for your challenge. we're attempting to isolate a test case. (and no, there's no compat library in the solaris case.)

Comment: we have isolated a test case at [link](http://family.redbarn.org/~vixie/getopttest.c) which fails as follows on debian stretch, opensuse 15, and suse tumbleweed.

`==2301== Invalid read of size 1
==2301==    at 0x4F08CAB: _getopt_internal_r (getopt.c:427)
==2301==    by 0x4F09D00: _getopt_internal (getopt.c:1175)
==2301==    by 0x4F09D42: getopt (getopt.c:1189)
==2301==    by 0x108B92: getopttest`

Comment: @PaulVixie Thanks, I have reported it as a [bug in glibc](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=25658). That should teach me to trust the Linux manpages ;-)

Comment: ty, but can you ask them for a feature test as part of the fix, so that i can avoid setting optreset=1 via #ifdef once it is no longer nec'y?